# How to prove $\{a_n\}$ is convergent?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(a_n+b_n+c_n)=\sqrt{3}$ and
>   $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2)=1$. Prove $\{a_n\}$ is
>   convergent.

I think this should apply the QM-AM inequality, i.e.
$$\left(\frac{a_n+b_n+c_n}{3}\right)^2\leq \frac{a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2}{3}.$$
Since $$\left(\frac{1}{3}\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(a_n+b_n+c_n)\right)^2=\frac{1}{3}\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2),$$
we have proper reason to speculate that $a_n=b_n=c_n$ for a sufficently large $n$. But how to give a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f_n=3(a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2), g_n=(a_n+b_n+c_n)^2, h_n=(a_n-b_n)^2+(a_n-c_n)^2+(c_n-b_n)^2$

We notice that $f_n-g_n=h_n \ge 0, f_n, g_n \to 3$, hence $h_n \to 0$, hence for every $\epsilon >0$ there is $N(\epsilon)$ s.t. $|a_n-b_n|, |a_n-c_n|,|c_n-b_n| \le \epsilon, n \ge N(\epsilon)$ which immediately implies $|a_n+b_n+c_n-3a_n| \le 2\epsilon,n \ge N(\epsilon)$ so, $a_n \to \frac{\sqrt 3}{3}$ and so do $b_n, c_n$

Comment: Maybe， we need take the sup-limit and inf-limit W.R.T:$$\frac{a_n+b_n+c_n}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\varepsilon<a_n<\frac{a_n+b_n+c_n}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\varepsilon$$ Then use the arbitariness of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @mengdie why? if $q_n \to L$ and $|q_n-p_n| \to 0$ it follows trivially that $p_n \to L$ by the triangle inequality as $|p_n-L| \le |p_n-q_n|+|q_n-L|$ when $L$ finite and kind of obvious if $L = \pm \infty$

Comment: Very simple and clever solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply QM-AM since we are not given that $a_n,b_n,c_n \ge 0$.

We have that

$$\frac{(a_n+b_n+c_n)^2}{3}=\frac{a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2+2(a_nb_n+b_nc_n+c_na_n)}{3}\to 1$$

and therefore $a_nb_n+b_nc_n+c_na_n \to 1$ and since by rearrangement inequality

$$a_nb_n+b_nc_n+a_nc_n \le a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2$$

with equality if and only if $a_n=b_n=c_n$ we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_nb_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} b_nc_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} c_na_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n^2=\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n^2=\lim_{n\to \infty} c_n^2=\frac13$$

and then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} c_n=\frac{\sqrt 3}3$$